# Pandas dataframe in pyspark to hive

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, hive, pyspark

How to send a pandas dataframe to a hive table?

I know if I have a spark dataframe, I can register it to a temporary table using

```
df.registerTempTable("table_name")
sqlContext.sql("create table table_name2 as select * from table_name")
```

but when I try to use the pandas dataFrame to registerTempTable, I get the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'registerTempTable'
```

Is there a way for me to use a pandas dataFrame to register a temp table or convert it to a spark dataFrame and then use it register a temp table so that I can send it back to hive.

Comment: have to convert, the error is clear the attribute doesn't exist for a pandas dataframe

Comment: yes, but I don't no how to convert a pandas dataframe to a spark dataframe.
I tried using 
    `sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)`
 but it only takes the schema and not the data inside the dataFrame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are trying to use pandas `df` instead of [Spark's DF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions).

Pandas DataFrame has no such method as `registerTempTable`.

you may try to create Spark DF from pandas DF.

**UPDATE:**

I've tested it under Cloudera (with installed [Anaconda parcel](https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/misc/parcels/), which includes Pandas module).

Make sure that you have set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` to your anaconda python installation (or another one containing Pandas module) on all your Spark workers (usually in: `spark-conf/spark-env.sh`)

Here is result of my test:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
>>> sdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)
>>> sdf.show()
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
| 98| 33| 75|
| 91| 57| 80|
| 20| 87| 85|
| 20| 61| 37|
| 96| 64| 60|
| 79| 45| 82|
| 82| 16| 22|
| 77| 34| 65|
| 74| 18| 17|
| 71| 57| 60|
+---+---+---+

>>> sdf.printSchema()
root
 |-- A: long (nullable = true)
 |-- B: long (nullable = true)
 |-- C: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: There is no way to convert pandas to spark DF? I can try writing all my functionality in spark df but  it doesn't work as flexibly as pandas.

Comment: yes, that only creates the schema but does not bring data.
Once you try let me know how it works for you.

Comment: or if you know another way to send the data back to hive without using a temp table, share that. I am not keen on having a temp table as long as I get the data back in hive.

Comment: did you get to try it at home?

Comment: ok well let me know if you try at some point later. I am still trying to figure this out, if I am unable to do this then I will try Scala for my work.

Comment: I will try this now and see if I am able to get it to work.

Comment: I was able to work this out. Although when i use the temptable to create a table in hive, it only creates the schema and does not push data. with a simple insert statement I was able to get that done(using sqlContext)

Answer (score 4):

first u need to convert pandas dataframe to spark dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
df = hive_context.createDataFrame(pd_df)
```

then u can create a temptable which is in memory:

```
df.registerTempTable('tmp')
```

now,u can use hive ql to save data into hive:

```
hive_context.sql("""insert overwrite table target partition(p='p') select a,b from tmp'''
```

note than:the hive_context must be keep to the same one!

Answer (score 0):

I converted my pandas df to a temp table by

1) Converting the pandas dataframe to spark dataframe:

```
spark_df=sqlContext.createDataFrame(Pandas_df)
```

2) Make sure that the data is *migrated* properly

```
spark_df.select("*").show()
```

3) Convert the spark dataframe to a temp table for querying.

```
spark_df.registerTempTable("table_name").
```

Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

By Following all the other answers here, I was able to convert a pandas dataframe to a permanent Hive table as follows:

```
# sc is a spark context created with enableHiveSupport()
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hc=HiveContext(sc)

# df is my pandas dataframe
sc.createDataFrame(df).registerTempTable('tmp')   

# sch is the hive schema, and tabname is my new hive table name
hc.sql("create table sch.tabname as select * from tmp")
```