# How to save Pandas dataframe to a hive table?

Tags: python, pandas, hive

I have pandas dataframe and I am trying to find the best way to save dataframe data to a hive table. One way is to save to csv file and load it to hive table. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919825/pandas-dataframe-in-pyspark-to-hive

Comment: check out odo,  http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/

Comment: These files are really small I am trying not to use spark for this purpose.

Comment: @Bob did you figure this out. What did you end up doing?

Comment: Without using PySpark: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57590374/12029183