# How to insert a pandas dataframe into an existing Hive external table using Python (without PySpark)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hive

I'm creating a connection string to Hive and running some SELECT queries on the Hive tables on that connection.

After performing some transfomrations upon the retrieved data, I'm creating a data frame `df_student_credits` that looks as follows

```
NAME_STUDENT_INITIAL    CREDITS_INITIAL     NAME_STUDENT_FINAL  CREDITS_FINAL   LOAD_DATE
John                    23                  John                25              21/03/2017
Alan                    19                  Alan                19              17/06/2018
Will                    24                  Will                26              02/08/2019
Lily                    25                  Lily                25              22/01/2019
```

Now, I want to insert this dataframe into a Hive external table that I'm creating using the below command:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS school_db.student_credits
(
NAME_STUDENT_INITIAL STRING,
CREDITS_INITIAL STRING,
NAME_STUDENT_FINAL STRING,
CREDITS_FINAL STRING,
LOAD_DATE STRING
)
LOCATION '/user/gradebook/student_credits/';
```

I want the insertions to be appended into the table everytime this script is run and the dataframe generated instead of overwriting the existing table data.

Almost every post I see shows the ways to do this using PySpark. But I'm can't use PySpark and I have to achieve this using the same python script that I'm using to fire SELECT queries.

I'm very new to Hive and a novice at Python. Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: please find my answer below. make sure that separator you choose for pandas dataframe has to match with FIELDS TERMINATED BY of your  create hive external table statement. Thanks

Comment: @vikrantrana I couldn't use your answer completely as it needs me to save the dataset into a csv. I just upvoted your answer  as it surely gave me some new ideas which I'm trying in my code. Thank you very much for your response. If I do finally end up using the similar logic for solving my problem, i will surely come back and choose yours as the correct answer.

Comment: Oh that sounds good. I didn't know of that before. I will look into this option too. Thanks a lot for mentioning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to read into pandas dataframe from Hive table and doing some transformation and saving that back to some Hive external table. Please refer below code as sample. Here I have read from Hive table into pandas dataframe and added some date column to it. Later I have used subprocess module to execute my shell, which will load data into Hive table which is partitioned on some date column.

```
from pyhive import hive
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
import datetime
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import subprocess
import sys

conn = hive.Connection(host="yourhost.com", port=10000, username="vikct001")
cursor = conn.cursor()

query="select user_id,country from test_dev_db.test_data"

start_time= datetime.datetime.now()

output_file='/home/vikct001/user/vikrant/python/test_data.csv'

data=pd.read_sql(query,conn)
data['current_date'] = pd.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(data)

data.to_csv(output_file, sep='|', encoding='utf-8',index=None)

hivequery=""" hive --hivevar loaded_date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") hive -e 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH "/home/vikct001/user/vikrant/python/test_data.csv" INTO TABLE test_dev_db.test_data_external PARTITION (loaded_date="${hivevar:loaded_date}")';"""

def save_to_hdfs(output_file):
        print("I am here")
        p=subprocess.Popen(hivequery,shell=True,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout,stderr = p.communicate()
        if p.returncode != 0:
            print stderr
            sys.exit(1)


save_to_hdfs(output_file)
end_time=datetime.datetime.now()

print 'processing ends', (start_time-end_time).seconds/60.0,' minutes'
```

**Table description:**

```
hive (test_dev_db)> desc test_dev_db.test_data_external;
OK
id                      int
country                 string
input_date              date
loaded_date             string

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type               comment

loaded_date             string
```

you can see that data has been loaded and created a partition with current date.

```
hive (test_dev_db)> show partitions test_dev_db.test_data_external;
OK
loaded_date=2019-08-21


hive (test_dev_db)> select * from test_dev_db.test_data_external;
OK
1       India   2019-08-21      2019-08-21
2       Ukraine 2019-08-21      2019-08-21
1       India   2019-08-21      2019-08-21
2       Ukraine 2019-08-21      2019-08-21
1       India   2019-08-21      2019-08-21
2       Ukraine 2019-08-21      2019-08-21
1       India   2019-08-21      2019-08-21
```

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers here before i get to the exact answer.

**HDFS is nothing without partitions**. In your case you haven't defined any partition. Leaving it as a default is never a good idea. It is your data and you must know how to partition that. So add a proper partition by clause.

Let us suppose LOAD_DATE is the column on which you want to set the partition. Dump the dataframe into a **parquet** format.
I am keeping the same path as the parquet path for the HDFS data.
Now go like below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS school_db.student_credits
(
NAME_STUDENT_INITIAL STRING,
CREDITS_INITIAL STRING,
NAME_STUDENT_FINAL STRING,
CREDITS_FINAL STRING
)
partitioned by (LOAD_DATE STRING
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'parquet.hive.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
  STORED AS
    INPUTFORMAT "parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat"
    OUTPUTFORMAT "parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetOutputFormat"
location '/user/gradebook/student_credits';

set hive.msck.path.validation=ignore;
msck repair table school_db.student_credits;
```

Here on the **`repair`** command is what you need to fire everyday. That will refresh the data and the new partitions as well.

On how to dump the dataframe into parquet file, use below

```
df_student_credits.write.mode("append").partitionBy("LOAD_DATE").parquet("user/gradebook/student_credits")
```

First create the parquet file and then the external table.
Let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: thanks for the suggestion on partitioning and code changes. I will keep that in mind. But how do I perform the actual insertion of my dataframe, say `df_student_credits`, into this Hive table?

Comment: df_student_credits.write.mode("append").partitionBy("LOAD_DATE").parquet("user/gradebook/student_credits")

Comment: it says: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'` any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: May be you can use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html to write into parquet format

Comment: Turns out I need to write the data in `orc` format instead of `parquet.` Is there a way for me to store my dataframe directly as an `orc` file at the HDFS location that I used in the my Hive table creation - but without using PySpark?