# What is the best way to export pandas dataframe to hive table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hadoop, hive

I was looking for help here (and in many other place):

1. [How to save Pandas dataframe to a hive table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53862365/how-to-save-pandas-dataframe-to-a-hive-table)
2. [Pandas dataframe in pyspark to hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919825/pandas-dataframe-in-pyspark-to-hive)
3. [How to insert a pandas dataframe into an existing Hive external table using Python (without PySpark)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590374/how-to-insert-a-pandas-dataframe-into-an-existing-hive-external-table-using-pyth)

But I don't think I completely understand the proposals presented, because I failed with any of them

What am I trying to do is:

1. Extract data from hive table from schema1 to python dataframe.
2. Do some operations on columns and save as pandas dataframe.
3. Export pandas dataframe to hive table schema2.

I made points 1-2 as follows:

1. Extract data from hive table to python dataframe.

```
transport = puretransport.transport_factory(host='my_host_name',
                                            port=10000,
                                            username='my_username',
                                            password='my_password',
                                            use_ssl=True)

engine = db.create_engine(f"hive://my_username@/schema1",
                          connect_args={'thrift_transport': transport})

print("Selecting data from table", end=" ")
tab1 = []
for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(
        """select * from schema1.my_table""", con=engine, chunksize=5):
    tab1.append(chunk)
df = pd.concat(tab1)
print("DONE")
```

2. Do some operations on columns and save as pandas dataframe.

```
my_code_returning_dataframe...
```

3. Export pandas dataframe to hive table schema2.

```
what_should_i_do_there?
```

Thank you in advance for any help.